# Reversing a string in c, problem using strlen function

Tags: c, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

I wrote a code to reverse a string, but the `strlen` function is giving me the wrong length of string, that's why the reversing of the string is not done properly. Here is the code I wrote:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reversestring(char string[], int start, int end);

int main() {
    char str[500];
    int n;
    n = strlen(str);
    reversestring(str, 0, n - 1);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    printf("The reverse string is %s", str);
    return 0;
}

void reversestring(char string[], int start, int end) {
    printf("enter the string:\n");
    scanf("%s", string);
    int temp;
    while (start < end) {
        //printf("insidewhile\n");
        temp = string[start];
        string[start] = string[end];
        string[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end --;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pop quiz: What are the contents of `str`? The one in your main function, not the `string` in your reverse function.

Comment: Any time you find yourself wanting to say that a basic and widely used piece of software, such as the `strlen` function, is giving wrong results you need to stop and tell yourself: "There is something going on I don't understand. The problem is in the software I wrote. I had better figure out what it is". Repeat (and debug) as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strlen()` can´t give you the length of a string, when its argument does not point to a valid string, which is the case on your example:

```
char str[500];
int n;
n = strlen(str);
```

`str` isn´t initialized with a string.

Providing a pointer to a `char` array which doesn´t contain a string as argument to `strlen()` causes undefined behavior.

Also `strlen()` doesn´t return an `int`. It´s return value is of type `size_t`.

Also use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` when input a string. It is a little bit more safe.

---

Solution:

Let the string get entered in `main()` into `str`, then use `strlen()` and thereafter call the `reversestring()` function:

```
char str[500];         
size_t n;

printf("enter the string:\n");
fgets(str,500,stdin);

n = strlen(str);   
reversestring(str, 0, n-1);
```

I also edited the function declaration and the `printf()` accordingly to take care of the `size_t` type.

---

Here is the full code ([Online Example](https://onlinegdb.com/BkeV-ZiQwL)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reversestring(char string[], size_t start, size_t end);

int main()
{
    char str[500];
    size_t n;

    printf("enter the string:\n");
    fgets(str,500,stdin);
    str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;    // removing trailing newline from fgets

    n = strlen(str);   
    reversestring(str, 0, n-1);

    printf("%zu\n", n);
    printf("The reverse string is %s", str);
    return 0;
}


void reversestring(char string[], size_t start, size_t end)
{
    int temp;
    while(start < end)
    {   //printf("insidewhile\n");
        temp = string[start];
        string[start] = string[end];
        string[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end --;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
enter the string:             
helloworld     
10                     
The reverse string is dlrowolleh
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `strlen` after the initialization of `str` and set a correct size of third argument of `reversestring`:

```cpp
size_t max_length = 128;

reversestring(str, 0, max_length);
n = strlen(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no string in the declared character array

```
{   char str[500];
    int n;
```

The character array is not initailzied. So this call

```
n = strlen(str);
```

results in undefined bahavior.

This code snippet from the function reversestring

```
printf("enter the string:\n");
scanf("%s", string);
```

shall be outside the function and used before the function is called.

The function should be declared at least like

```
char * reversestring( char string[], size_t n );
```

There is no need to declare the function with three parameters like you did

```
void reversestring(char string[], int start, int end);
```

because a call to this function can be substituted for the call of the previous shown function like

```
reversestring( string + start, end - start + 1 );
```

Also pay attention to that using the format `%s` does not allow to enter a sentence. Moreover using this format specifier with the function `scanf` is unsafe, And the function `strlen` has the return type `size_t`.

Here is the function definition

```
char * reversestring( char s[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i -1];
        s[n-i-1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reversestring( char s[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i -1];
        s[n-i-1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum  { N = 500 };
    char s[N];

    printf( "Enter a string: " );

    fgets( s, N, stdin );

    s[ strcspn( s, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    size_t n = strlen( s );

    puts( reversestring( s, n ) );

    char *p = strchr( s, ' ' );

    if ( p != NULL && ( p = strchr( p + 1, ' ' ) ) != NULL )
    {
        reversestring( s, p - s );
        puts( s );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look for example like

```
Enter a string: Hello Shivam Gupta
atpuG mavihS olleH
Shivam Gupta olleH
```